# Power BI model flushing

Tags: sql, powerbi

I have the following technical problem:

At work, we need to compare user performance using user data in the database every week for four weeks (the current week and the last three weeks).
Each week has a different user performance percentage which changes every day, but we compare it on a weekly basis.

In order to accomplish this, I came up with the following solution:

1. Use four models in power bi with M1 connected to the database and refreshes every week.
2. create three more models M3, M2, M1 where every week their content updates according to the following criteria:

M1 -> updates to M2 content

M2 -> updates to M3 content

M3 -> updates to M4 content

M4 -> updates to current week's data from the database

Can this be done in Power BI?

If it's not possible to implement this solution in Power BI, is there any other possible way to do this?[image]

Comment: Bit over complicated, just load in 4 weeks worth of data, maybe look at incremental refresh to load in the days changes and also filter out data greater than 4 weeks, then use some time intelligence functions over the single table to find the performance  differences

Comment: yes, you're right, but because the dates are not accurate in the database, so far I've found the most accurate way of doing it is to take snapshots of the database